# issue with vmd install not working any more. lubuntu 12.10

Tags: lubuntu

I had [vmd](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) working on my lubuntu 64 bit but all of a sudden I was getting errors when I tried to run it. I tried reinstalling it but no joy.

The error I now get when I try to run

> > rlwrap: No match.

I don't use make unless I have to so I don't know all that much about it.

I have removing vmd completely to see if that helped. I tried the suggestions it made (I am sorry, I can't remember the details but it was moaning about CUDA and my graphic drivers for a while.

I had not updated it or anything. It was fine until I went away from the computer and came back to it like that.

If nobody can help I will try reinstalling my system and see if that helps.

Comment: once you uninstall rlwrap where do you type make install?

Comment: I wrote a blog giving instructions on how to install vmd a while back. See if that helps you http://blog.thismagpie.com/2012/11/how-to-install-vmd-on-linux-ubuntu-64.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is how I fixed it.

I uninstalled rlwrap. hit

> make install

and then vmd ran!

Cheers.